# OpenGL - gpu memory exceeded, possible scenarios

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management, glsl

I can use `glTexImage2D` or `glBufferData` to send some data to the gpu memory. Let's assume that I request driver to send more data to the gpu but the gpu memory is already full. I probably get GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY. What might happen with a rendering thread ? What are possible scenarios ? Is it possible that a rendering thread will be terminated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the actual OpenGL implementation. But the most likely scenario is, that you'll just encounter a serious performance drop, but things will just keep working.

OpenGL uses an abstract memory model, for which actual implementation threat the GPU's own memory as a cache. In fact for most OpenGL implementation when you load texture data it doesn't even go directly to the GPU at first. Only when it's actually required for rendering it gets loaded into the GPU RAM. If there are more textures in use than fit into GPU RAM, textures are swapped in and out from GPU RAM as needed to complete the rendering.

Older GPU generations required for a texture to completely fit into their RAM. The GPUs that came out after 2012 actually can access texture subsets from host memory as required thereby lifting that limit. In fact you're sooner running into maximum texture dimension limits, rather than memory limits (BT;DT).

Of course other, less well developed OpenGL implementations may bail out with an out of memory error. But at least for AMD and NVidia that's not an issue.

Comment: A driver can hold more data than can be stored in the GPU ram. Is it possible that  a driver buffer can grow until host ram is available ?

Comment: @Irbis: Indeed that's the case. In fact, once the host system runs out of RAM, but there's swap space configured, then swap space will be used. Unfortunately it is not possible to explicitly create a connection between OpenGL objects' data and block storage (mmap some file's contents which would be a texture image and passing that pointer to the graphics API to use on demand); hopefully that will be a possibility with Vulkan (uses host managed buffers and data descriptors).