# glDrawArrays does not render entire point cloud

Tags: opengl, point-clouds

I'm trying to render huge point clouds (~150M) but OpenGL only renders part (~52M) of it. When rendering smaller datasets (<40M) everything works fine. I'm using single VBO. When using multiple VBOs, points get rendered but rendering is awfully slow, which is expected. My element has a size of 44bytes and GPU has 3GB of memory available. This should be enough for nearly ~70M points but I can render as much as 100M points with multiple VBOs. **Is there any OpenGL specific limitation per VBO I'm not aware of?**.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cloud.size() * sizeof(Point), cloud.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// lot of other code
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, cloud.size());
```

Comment: You aren't calling glBufferData every frame, are you?

Comment: Are you verifying that `glBufferData()` isn't setting the error state to `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`?

Comment: I'm not. This is just pseudo code. In fact I use dirty flag to update buffer only when data changes.

Comment: I tested glGetError and it returns 0.

Comment: How many VBOs are you taking about? 100, 1000, 10000?

Comment: @Ripi2, I tested with 4VBOs and it works.

Comment: Please, explain more. When does it becomes slower? When does it stop drawing? You have showed data size, but not number of VBOs and gl-calls.

Comment: dummy question: does cloud.size() and cloud.data() work proper for the big data configurations?

Comment: @keksnicoh, yes cloud is of type std::vector<Point> and uses size_t for size, so that works fine. Also tested. The amount of data transfered to GPU is 148M points * 44bytes ≃ 6.5GB which is beyond GPU memory but without opengl error (GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081555/opengl-gpu-memory-exceeded-possible-scenarios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like some part of your system uses 32-bit unsigned integers to store the size of the buffers, thus passing `148M*44bytes` overflows and gets converted to about `54.9M` or `50.4M` depending on whether your megabytes are binary or decimal. I'd start with checking your OpenGL binding library to see that the prototypes it declares correctly use 64-bit types. If it does then the bug must be in the OpenGL drivers.

To transfer more than 4GB data to the buffer you may try using one of the other available functions: `glBufferSubData` and `glBufferStorage`, or memory-map the buffer with `glMapBufferRange`, which might workaround the limitation of 4GB.

Another thing to consider is to use one VAO but split the data between multiple buffers. Presumably your `Point` consists of different attributes, like position, color, etc... You can put each of them in a separate buffer and still use one VAO and one draw call. You can also optimize the types of the attributes you use (e.g. don't use floats where shorts or bytes would do) and the layout of the structure (check that there's no unnecessary padding between the fields).

Comment: In order to use `glBufferSubData` I think you first need to call `glBufferData` with desired size (which is `GLsizei`) and usage, and then use `glBufferSubData` for updating parts of it. Do I understand that right?

As for `glBufferStorage`. I think this would solve my problems but I don't have OpenGL 4.4 available. 

I guess I'll have to use one VBO per 2^32bytes of data. Thank you!

Comment: Well, `glBufferSubData` indeed expects the memory for the buffer to be already allocated, which is what `glBufferStorage` is for. As you can see by the type they are using, they are newer functions indeed. You might still check if you have the `GL_ARB_buffer_storage` extension supported which introduced `glBufferStorage`.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `glBufferData` uses the type `GLsizeiptr` for the `size` parameter which is explicitely specified to be `ptrbits` wide, where `ptrbits` is the number of bits used for addresses in the client address space.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I _did_ read the 4.5 spec. I also checked back in the 2.0 spec if the wording has been different before. `BufferData` uses a `sizeiptr` in both variants, and `sizeiptr` is well-specified in both variants, too. There is a difference, though: in 2.0,, the bit withs are guaranteed minimums, in 4.5, they are exactly required. It doesn't change the picture, though.

Comment: @derhass: You're right, my brain plays tricks on me. I definitely read the spec too, but have seen `GLsizei`written there :X. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think memory is a problem in fact i'd say your program makes too many drawing calls . You should try with  glDrawArraysInstanced() . For that you need to provide new position for every instance in the vertex shader... maybe that will solve your problem :D.
I'm sorry if i cannot provide you with details ,my skills in OpenGL got a bit dull , but i am planning on recovering asap :D .i hope it helps .